# Can AD Distribution Group be used for authorizing users?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, authorize-attribute

All the users I want to let into the admin section of my app are in a distribution group but not a security group.  Can I use a distribution group in the Usre.IsInRole() method and in the Authorize(Role="Domain\DistribGroup")] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't. Distribution groups play no part in security at all. They are used solely for email distribution via Outlook or Exchange etc.

Answer (score 1):

No, rather you can use Email enabled Security group - this will allow both controlling security access & sending emails.